# libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I converted a python project to executable by pyinstaller. so I have

```
dist/
    projectname/
                project
                <somefiles>.so
                include/
                lib/
```

I want to mv `<somefiles>.so` into a directory in order to make it more understandable. but when I do that I have the error:

```
Error loading Python lib libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

how can I have the following tree:

```
dist/
    projectname/
                project
                so/
                   <somefiles>.so
                include/
                lib/
```

Comment: I'd look at http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#extending-the-path